# cannot assign to 'total' because it is a constant or a read only property for function get total(){}

Tags: angular, typescript

When I use this command `ng build --prod` in my project show me this error.
cannot assign to 'total' because it is a constant or a read only property for function get total(){}

My function is:

```
  get total() {
         return this.products
          .map(p => p.Unit_price * p.Quantity)
          .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      }
```

Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="addsale" (ngSubmit)="onaddsale()" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
      <label for="total">Total {{total}} ALL</label>
      <input formControlName="total" id="total" type="text" class="validate" [value]="total" [(ngModel)]="total">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
      <label for="amount_paid">Amount Paid:</label>
      <input formControlName="amount_paid" id="amount_paid" [value]="total" type="text" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="total">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
      <label for="total">Subtotal</label>
      <input formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" type="text" class="validate" [value]="total" [(ngModel)]="total">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Ts form:

```
   this.addsale = this.fb.group({
      'amount_paid': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
       'Subtotal': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'total': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
```

Any idea please?

Comment: this works for me. Whant angular and cli versions are you using? can you run "ng serve"?

Comment: Have you tried without 'get' before total() ?

Comment: Does it work if you just 'return 5'; (for example)?

Comment: @ForestG   "@angular/cdk": "^5.1.1",  "@angular/cli": "^1.6.2", when I run ng serve, work good

Comment: Can you show where you use it? Or where you use a `total` variable?

Comment: @David I edit my post

Comment: You have used ngModel+value+formcontrolname. One of them is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Building with the `--prod` flag acutally builds with aot, which is a lot stricter than when just using ng serve.

I think it is because your `[(ngModel)]` is set to `total` for all fields, and using 2 way bindings (get/set); you've got a conflict with the `total` getter

Since the total is calculated, I don't think it makes sense to have a 2-way binding for `total`, it should be readonly. And subtotal/amount paid should not use `total` for ngModel

Comment: Please, Can you suggest any solution for this, and I have this problem when use `[value]="total" type="text" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="total"` Or any example to calculate total please?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but in my case referring to the valid status of the form.

```
<-- HTML-->
<button 
    type="submit"
    [(disabled)]="!loginForm.valid">
    Enter
</button>
```

What worked for me was assigning that check to a new public variable.

```
<-- JS -->
public validForm: boolean;

 ngOnInit() {
     this.validForm = this.loginForm.valid;
 }
<-- HTML -->
<button 
    type="submit" 
    [(disabled)]="!validForm">
    Entrar
</button>
```

<--- EDIT --->

Also works if we use only one way data binding

```
<button 
    type="submit" 
    [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
    Entrar
</button>
```