# Cannot assign to 'total' because it is a constant or a read-only property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, readonly

I run `ng build --prod` in my project.

That I found is this error:

> src\app\components\xxxx\xxxx.component.html(116,100): : Cannot assign
>   to 'total' because it is a constant or a read-only property.

In this line I have this code:

```html
<input formControlName="total" id="total" type="text" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="total">
```

I used `[(ngModel)]="total"` --> because I want the value to be saved even without modifying it. If I used `[value]="total"` this error doesn't exist, but my value doesn't saved If I not modify.

and this total I get by this function in ts. This is Read Only

```
get total() {
    return this.products
      .map(p => p.p_Unit_price * p.p_Quantity)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
```

This total, show me total from all product.

How to modify this code, that working ok?

Edit:

Html code:

```html
<form [formGroup]="addsale" (ngSubmit)="onaddsale()">
  <table align="center" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr style="color:black;">
        <th>p_Product_type_id</th>
        <th>p_product_id</th>
        <th>p_Unit_price</th>
        <th>p_Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="group" *ngFor="let item of products">
        <td>{{item.p_Product_type_id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.p_product_id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.p_Unit_price}}</td>
        <td>{{item.p_Quantity}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
      <label for="total">Total {{total}} ALL</label>
      <input formControlName="total" id="total" type="text" class="validate" [value]="total" [(ngModel)]="total">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
      <label for="total">Subtotal</label>
      <input formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" type="text" class="validate" [value]="total" [(ngModel)]="total">
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <div id="add_homebox_button_container" class="row" style="float: right;">
    <button id="add_client_button" type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">
      Register
    </button>
</form>
```

Ts code:

```
export class component implements OnInit {
  constructor(.............
  ) {

    this.addsale = this.fb.group({
      'Subtotal': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'products': this.fb.array([]),
      'total': new FormControl('', Validators.required),

    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.allproducts();

  allproducts() {
    this.products = this.ps.getProduct();
  }


  onaddsale() {
    this.areWeWaiting = true;
    let sale = this.addsale.value
    sale.products = this.products
    let newSale = new Sale(sale);

    this.ws.saleitemcreate(newSale).subscribe(
      result => {
        if (result === true) {
          Materialize.toast('Successfully', 4000);
        } else {
          this.areWeWaiting = false;
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.areWeWaiting = false;
      }
    );
  }

  get total() {
       return this.products
      .map(p => p.p_Unit_price * p.p_Quantity)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: You would need to [add a setter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44511577/643039)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot assign to 'total' because it is a constant or a read only property for function get total(){}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554078/cannot-assign-to-total-because-it-is-a-constant-or-a-read-only-property-for-fu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[value]="total"` and add the total to saved values when saving. You do not need to use the form to collect the values for saving. You can handle this in your component.

I'd say that using `ngModel` just to pass some value for saving is a bit hacky way.

I'd edit the `onaddsale` method to add the total to the sale. Then you could delete the `total` from the `fb.group()` and remove the `formControlName="total"` from template as well, since you do not really need that.

```
  onaddsale() {
    this.areWeWaiting = true;
    let sale = this.addsale.value;
    sale.products = this.products;
    // pass total here
    sale.total = this.total;
    let newSale = new Sale(sale);
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Please look again,  I edit my post with full code. Thanx

Comment: Please In this demo, I need  sometimes  to change the value, Demo example is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-36akqo?file=app/hello.component.ts  Can you help me,  how to change value in Amount Paid? Thanx

Comment: You can use `setValue` described in [this tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#the-data-model-and-the-form-model)

Comment: Yes I use `setValue` in a functon `UpdateForm(event)` but nothing changes https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m8phbo?file=app/hello.component.ts  Please look in console, when you change a value and submit form.

Comment: I an see the value changing in the console. I do not understand what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you need to open another question.

Comment: Yes I know, I open another question for this, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240387/i-cant-submit-a-value-input-when-use-change  If you can please looks again and help me. Thank you