# change input value angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, onchange

Please, can you suggest me how to submit my value when I change it? So, I want to submit `amount_paid` when I change this value. For solution this, I create a function change that return me value. This value I need to submit. I tried this code:

Template code:

```
 <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
      <label for="amount_paid">Amount Paid:</label>
      <input id="amount_paid" [value]="amountpaid" type="number" class="validate" (change)="updateForm($event)">
 </div>
```

Ts code:

```
    this.addsale = this.fb.group({
      'invoice_number': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]),
      'client_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'amount_paid': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'products': this.fb.array([]),
    });

  updateForm(ev: any) {
    this.addsale['controls']['amount_paid'].setValue(ev.target.value);
    console.log(ev.target.value)
  }

  onaddsale() {
    let sale = this.addsale.value;
    sale.amount_paid = this.amountpaid; //I used this, because I want to submit this value If I don't want to change. 
    let newSale = new Sale(sale);
    console.log(newSale)
    console.log(this.addsale.controls.amount_paid.value) // Value input when I chane
   }

  get amountpaid() {
    return this.products
      .map(p => p.p_Unit_price * p.p_Quantity)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
```

Please I have 2 situation, 1, I submit value input, ex, 100. This work correctly. and 2. I submit input value when I change this value, so, from 100 I want to change 90, and this 90 I want to submit. My function submit also this first value `sale.amount_paid = this.amountpaid;`

**UPDATE:** [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dv5yoc?file=app/app.component.ts) example for  my problem

The problem is, amount_paid field should be modified, and the modified value should be preserved. How to modify my value? I want the field two binding, if I can't change, submit   `get amountpaid() {}` otherwise submit my value input.

Image 1 I save the form without changing the value.
[image]
Image 2 I save the form with the changed value, but the value doesn't change. show in console.

[image]

Comment: Don't mix [value] property with formcontrolName

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. amount_paid template should look like this:

`<input formControlName="amount_paid" id="amount_paid" type="number" class="validate">`

2. And in .ts:

   `this.addsale.controls['amount_paid'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
     amount_paid is in value and it's called every time the value changes.
   });`

or for the whole form:

```
this.addsale.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    // whole form object is in value and it's called every time any form field changes.
});
```

Edit based on the comments and your example:
Here is the [working solution](https://angular-57jwjv.stackblitz.io). At least I hope I understand you correctly this time.

Comment: I used `[value]="amountpaid"` because this return value from this `get amountpaid() {}`

Comment: You dont have to, and you should do it like that. You can do it as you do somewhere in your code: `this.addsale['controls']['amount_paid'].setValue(ev.target.value);` You are combining template driven forms and reactive forms pattern. It's a bad approach. Use one or the other.

Comment: Please, I don't understand, How to calculate my amountpaid()? If I write like your answer, for me doesn't display input. In this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175365/cannot-assign-to-total-because-it-is-a-constant-or-a-read-only-property, I show all my code, only in this I have different problem. Please look again. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you need. Can you try to describe it better please?

Comment: I am creating an invoice, in this invoice decides all products, price, quantity, name etc. The amount of products is calculated by the function `get amountpaid () {}`. So far it works very well. In this case, I have to make it possible for this value to change, in case it will be needed. In my code, the changed value is not saved. Please, try this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arvwvn?file=app/hello.component.ts

Comment: In this exp , I want to change Amount Paid. Try to create product, total and Amount Paid calculate automatic, change Amount Paid and submit, the value in Amount Paid don't submit change value

Comment: I still don't understand :( If you are asking how you can change the value of amount_paid without using the [value] binding, then the answer is: `this.addsale.controls.['amount_paid'].setValue(someValue);`

Comment: Please, look example. I post in my comment.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arvwvn?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the example previously. I updated my answer with a link to the example, with the problem fixed (I hope). Check it out. If it is what you are looking for, then please mark this answer as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, i can't see your change code. In demo version, that I want doesn't work ok. I need to change value in Amount Paid, 
this field should be modified, and the modified value should be submit.

Comment: I update my post, I think I have explained better what I'm looking for. Thanks