# I can't submit a value input when use (change)

Tags: angular, typescript, onchange

In my project I want to create an invoice. In this invoice I calculate value with a function `get subtotal(){}`, totally work good. Now, If I change this subtotal, for example,  I want to make a discount from 100 to 90.

I've tried this code but it does not work. Please, can you suggest me how to solve this issue?
Html code:

```
  <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
      <input formControlName="Subtotal " id="Subtotal " [value]="subtotal " type="number" class="validate" (change)="updateForm($event)">
    </div>
```

ts code:

```
  updateForm(event) {
    console.log(event)
    let amountpaidd = event.target.value
     this.addsale['controls']['Subtotal '].setValue(amountpaidd );
   }
  onaddsale() {
    let sale = this.addsale.value;
    sale.Subtotal = this.subtotal;
    let newSale = new Sale(sale);
    console.log(newSale)}

 get subtotal() {
    return this.products
      .map(p => p.p_Unit_price * p.p_Quantity)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
```

Thank you!

Update:

```
this.addsale = this.formbuilder.group({
      'Subtotal ': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'products': this.formbuilder.array([]),
    });
```

Comment: try (keyup) it's the native event generated after a key is pressed

Comment: isn't this redundant? You're setting the form value of the same control that changed. You've already bound with formControlName="Subtotal"

Comment: @toskv I tried `(keyup)` but it is not solution my problem. In html, I set `[value]="subtotal"` in this, subtotal is the value that generate from this function `get subtotal() {}` , and in function `onaddsale() {}` I set `sale.Subtotal = this.subtotal;` This submit first value, and not change value. In console,     `console.log(amountpaidd)` my value change, but I can't submit it. Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have a precalculated value in there, then just set the value of the control. Do not use the view (HTML) to pass the value back and forth.

First, create your form using the form builder.

Then, set the value from subtotal using `this.addSale.controls.Subtotal.setValue(this.subtotal)`. Do this whenever the subtotal changes.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.productList.subscribe(productList => {
    this.products = productList;
    this.addsale.controls.Subtotal.setValue(this.subtotal)
  });
}
```

Do **not** use `sale.Subtotal = this.subtotal`.

`let sale = this.addsale.value` already does that.

in your view, use the basic reactive form binding.

```
 <input formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" type="number" class="validate">
```

Your value should get updated whenever you call the `setValue(this.subtotal)`

The user can overwrite the value of course. But it may get overwritten if you add more products or so. If you want to prevent that, you should watch if user has done that and prevent updating the value with new subtotal anymore.

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kkkzw9?file=app/hello.component.ts) based on demo you provided in comment.

Comment: Please, can you look this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lkqggu?file=app/hello.component.ts ? 1. Please add a product, the product appears in the table, subtotal and total. 2. Please add a sale when it adds the sale, and all inputs are displayed on the console. 3. When I change the value in the submission, and the sales registration, my contribution value does not change.

Comment: Your demo does not work, maybe your forgot to save it.

Comment: Look again please https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qaqceb?file=app/hello.component.ts

Comment: I did. I've updated the answer. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kkkzw9?file=app/hello.component.ts